# Issue Using Vue3 With pinia

Tags: vuejs3, devtools, pinia

I'm having an issue using pinia, Previously I used vuex on my project but I wanted to migrate to pinia to handle my store. So I think, I setup pinia  properly. So I can run the serv of my application without issues. But here is what i get when i open the page (PS: The vue dev tools is not anymore detected):

[image]

Here is my file package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "ecomm-challenge",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^3.0.0-4",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "pinia": "^2.0.14",
    "vue": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.15",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.26.5",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-cli-plugin-pinia": "~0.1.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

and here you can find my main.js file:

```js
import { createApp } from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";

import { faCartShopping } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { createPinia } from "pinia";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";
library.add(faCartShopping);
const pinia = createPinia();
createApp(App)
  .use(pinia)
  .component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon)
  .mount("#app");
```

Here is my github if someone want to check the code: https://github.com/Elsong1120/Ecomm-challenge

Thanks to anyone who will help me.

Comment: Maybe somewhere in your code, you use pina before `createPinia()` is called

Comment: @Duannx i don't think so but i edit my post to put my github for anyone who want  to take a look at my code

Comment: You are not using the setup script. So you need to use [helper functions](https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/options-api.html#usage-without-setup) in your options API

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issues this is what helped me:

1st create a new file in store folder `\store\store.js` wich looks like this:

```js
import { createPinia, setActivePinia } from "pinia";
const pinia = createPinia();
setActivePinia(pinia);
export default pinia;
```

2nd import the pinia (exported from `\store\store.js`) into your `main.js`

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import pinia from './stores/store.js';
import App from './App.vue';

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(pinia)

app.mount('#app');
```