# Installing Pinia in vue3 project: exports not found in 'vue-demi'

Tags: vue.js, npm, dependencies, vuejs3, pinia

I'm workig on a Vue 3 project in Visual Studio 2022.
I use npm as package manager and I want to install [pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).
So I did: `npm install pinia`

I also added Pinia in my vue application as plugin:

```
// In main.js
import { createPinia } from 'pinia'

createApp(App)
.use(createPinia())
.use(/*...*/)
.use(/*...*/)
.mount('#app')
```

When I build the app, the building process completes to the end and the debugging of the app starts. But when local debugging webserver opens, it shows around 50 errors in its console window, all of the same kind. The webbrowser instance in the Visual Studio debug process opens, showing my running app. But the webpack dev error overlay shows over the application, showing that same errors:

```
ERROR in ../node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 25:55-61
export 'inject' (imported as 'inject') was not found in 'vue-demi' (possible exports: Fragment, KeepAlive, Suspense, Teleport, Transition, TransitionGroup, Vue, Vue2, hasInjectionContext, install, isVue2, isVue3, version)
ERROR in ../node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 614:43-48
export 'toRaw' (imported as 'toRaw') was not found in 'vue-demi' (possible exports: Fragment, KeepAlive, Suspense, Teleport, Transition, TransitionGroup, Vue, Vue2, hasInjectionContext, install, isVue2, isVue3, version)
ERROR in ../node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 807:12-17
export 'watch' (imported as 'watch') was not found in 'vue-demi' (possible exports: Fragment, KeepAlive, Suspense, Teleport, Transition, TransitionGroup, Vue, Vue2, hasInjectionContext, install, isVue2, isVue3, version)
ERROR in ../node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 807:24-29
export 'unref' (imported as 'unref') was not found in 'vue-demi' (possible exports: Fragment, KeepAlive, Suspense, Teleport, Transition, TransitionGroup, Vue, Vue2, hasInjectionContext, install, isVue2, isVue3, version)
ERROR in ../node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 864:27-34
export 'markRaw' (imported as 'markRaw') was not found in 'vue-demi' (possible exports: Fragment, KeepAlive, Suspense, Teleport, Transition, TransitionGroup, Vue, Vue2, hasInjectionContext, install, isVue2, isVue3, version)

And so on........
```

I don't understand why installing pinia is so problematic. There are more issues posted on the internet about installing pinia, and some of them look very comparable to my case.

I found this similar looking cases:

- [Issue Using Vue3 With pinia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72605826/issue-using-vue3-with-pinia)
- [SyntaxError: The requested module 'vue-demi' does not provide an export named 'hasInjectionContext' while running tests with Pinia in Vitest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76311531/syntaxerror-the-requested-module-vue-demi-does-not-provide-an-export-named-h)
- ["hasInjectionContext" is not exported by "node_modules/vue-demi/lib/index.mjs", imported by "node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76294403/hasinjectioncontext-is-not-exported-by-node-modules-vue-demi-lib-index-mjs)
  https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/2210

It looks like there must be something wrong with the dependencies. But I cannot solve my problem, and my understanding of package managers is low. I just see them as a black box and install the packages I need.

This is in the log file:

```
# npm resolution error report

While resolving: myprojectname@0.1.0
Found: vue@3.3.4
node_modules/vue
  vue@"^3.3.6" from the root project
  peerOptional vue@"^2 || ^3.2.13" from @vue/babel-preset-app@5.0.8
  node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-app
    @vue/babel-preset-app@"^5.0.8" from @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.8
    node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel
      dev @vue/cli-plugin-babel@"~5.0.0" from the root project
  peerOptional vue@"*" from @vue/babel-preset-jsx@1.4.0
  node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-jsx
    @vue/babel-preset-jsx@"^1.1.2" from @vue/babel-preset-app@5.0.8
    node_modules/@vue/babel-preset-app
      @vue/babel-preset-app@"^5.0.8" from @vue/cli-plugin-babel@5.0.8
      node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel
        dev @vue/cli-plugin-babel@"~5.0.0" from the root project
  peer vue@"3.3.4" from @vue/compat@3.3.4
  node_modules/@vue/compat
    @vue/compat@"^3.3.4" from the root project
  peer vue@"3.3.4" from @vue/server-renderer@3.3.4
  node_modules/@vue/server-renderer
    @vue/server-renderer@"3.3.4" from vue@3.3.4
  peer vue@"^3.2.0" from vue-router@4.2.4
  node_modules/vue-router
    vue-router@"^4.2.4" from the root project
  peer vue@"^3.0.2" from vuex@4.0.2
  node_modules/vuex
    vuex@"^4.0.2" from the root project

Could not resolve dependency:
pinia@"^2.1.3" from the root project

Conflicting peer dependency: vue@3.3.6
node_modules/vue
  peer vue@">= 2.5 < 2.7" from @vue/composition-api@1.7.2
  node_modules/@vue/composition-api
    peerOptional @vue/composition-api@"^1.4.0" from pinia@2.1.7
    node_modules/pinia
      pinia@"^2.1.3" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

What am I overlooking? To me it looks like there's just something wrong with dependencies. But I really don't know how to fix this. I also tried uninstalling pinia and re-installing it. I manually added `"pinia": "..."` in the `"dependencies"` object in *package.json*. But then the compilation totally fails.

Lastly, here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "myprojectname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/compat": "^3.3.4",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.3",
    "bootstrap-vue": "^2.23.1",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "jest": "^29.6.2",
    "jest-editor-support": "^31.1.0",
    "vue": "^3.3.6",
    "vue-router": "^4.2.4",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.6",
    "node-sass": "^9.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.64.2",
    "sass-loader": "^13.3.2",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "@babel/eslint-parser"
    },
    "rules": {
      "vue/multi-word-component-names": "off",
      "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": "off",
      "no-unused-vars": "off"
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead",
    "not ie 11"
  ]
}
```

And when I do `npm list vue` the output is:

[image]

I really hope someone can be of any help.

Comment: package.json is incomplete because there's no pinia there. You can try to remove node_modules and reinstall. If this doesn't help, remove it and also lock file and try again. npm version also matters. It's unclear why `@vue/composition-api` was installed, it shouldn't be in your case. I spotted no other potential problems. If the problem persists, please, provide a way to reproduce.

Comment: I installed `@vue/composition-api` manually because I read somewhere it is required so I tried. I added `"pinia": "2.1.7"` to the `package.json` and then the "export not found" compilation errors occur. But I also tried removing the pinia dependency in my package.json, to see what happens and maybe some things would "refresh" when recompiling and then adding pinia back to the package.json. But no success.
Also, when I try to `npm uninstall @vue/composition-api` to clean it up because it is not necessary, it just says "up to date" and it seems it doesn't actually remove it.

Comment: npm version is **9.6.7**

Comment: No, this package isn't needed. It won't be removed if it's not in package.json, could possibly be fixed with complete dep reinstall like described above. Needs a reproduction at this moment, looks like a problem with deps that has to be debugged

Comment: I deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and rebuilt the project. Now the errors are gone and everything works without issues. Thank you. Hopefully it stays good now, otherwise I'll let you know.